# Prove a certain imaginary quadratic field contains three ideal classes.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideal-class-group

I'm trying to show $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-31}]$ has three distinct ideal classes, but something keeps going wrong and I can only find the identity and one other class.

I found $|d_{K}| = 31$ because $-31 \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, and using Minkowski's Bound I computed $\frac{1}{2} \frac{4}{\pi} \sqrt{31} < 4$, so I need only check primes 2 and 3 (I feel like this is where I may be missing something).

$\langle 2 \rangle$ splits into $\left\langle 2, \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{-31}}{2} \right\rangle$ which I can show is not principal by considering the norm of an arbitrary element needs to equal $2$ $\implies$ $N(\alpha) = N\left(\frac{a + b\sqrt{-31}}{2}\right) = \frac{a^{2} + 31b^{2}}{4} \neq 2$.

My problems is with $\langle 3 \rangle$ because it is prime in $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ due to $-31$ not being congruent to a square modulo $3$. Thus $\langle 3 \rangle$ is equivalent to the identity in the ideal class group, therefore the ideal class group has only two classes.

Can anyone see where I am making a mistake? Your comments would be much appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: I think the two ideals $(2,\frac{1\pm\sqrt{-31}}{2})$ belong to different classes? Or maybe I miss some element $\alpha\in\mathcal O_K$ such that $(2,\frac{1+\sqrt{-31}}{2})\cdot(\alpha)=(2,\frac{1-\sqrt{-31}}{2})$?

Comment: Thank you! I never considered that.  I kept thinking the prime factors had to be in the same class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As awllower points out, $\mathfrak{p}=(2,\frac12(1+\sqrt{-31}))$
and $\mathfrak{p}'=(2,\frac12(1-\sqrt{-31}))$ are in different ideal
classes. Clearly $\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{p}'=(2)$ so
$[\mathfrak{p}]$ and $[\mathfrak{p}']$ are inverse classes. Also
as there is no norm $2$ element in the ring of integers, each is non-principal. But $(\frac12(1+\sqrt{-31}))=\mathfrak{p}^3$ as this
ideal has norm $8$ and cannot be divisible by $\mathfrak{p}'$.
Thus $[\mathfrak{p}]$ is an ideal class of order $3$ in the classgroup
and $[\mathfrak{p}']=[\mathfrak{p}]^{-1}=[\mathfrak{p}]^2$.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much.  I kept thinking the two factors were in the same class. This makes a lot of sense though.

Comment: Could you explain why it is that $p'$ doesn't divide $p^3$? (not sure how to type a gothic p)

Comment: @celticburns, Well $\mathfrak p$ certainly does, and if  $\mathfrak p'$ did so too then so would $(2)=\mathfrak p\mathfrak p'$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: I am not an expert in this topic, but it looks to me that there are just two [reduced binary quadratic forms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReducedBinaryQuadraticForm.html) with discriminant $-31$, namely $a^2\pm ab+8b^2$ and $2a^2\pm ab+4b^2$. Isn't a discrepancy here?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Looks like you listed four there.... $a^2+ab+8b^2$ and $a^2-ab+8b^2$ are properly equivalent ... the latter is not reduced by the usual definition. $2a^2+ab+4b^2$ and $2a^2-ab+4b^2$ are not properly equivalent, and neither are equivalent to $a^2+ab+8b^2$. Both are reduced. So of the four forms you list, three are reduced.  In general I would counsel against believing Wolfram's web pages; there are errors on the web-page cited. In particular it classifies the wrong class as positive definite.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: that makes perfectly sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  In case of interest, I recommend Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms. He does a good job of relating forms and quadratic fields. Also, while he is consistent with older texts, he does very well on forms with odd $ab$ coefficient. For this specific question, recommend Hudson and Williams on class number three,  http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hudson_Williams_1991.pdf